# view.layer.cornerCurve = .continuous for android (Jetpack Compose)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

How to manipulate corner radius curves for a Box? In iOS, you can use the following line:

`view.layer.cornerCurve = .continuous`

to get a continuous cornerCurve for a view. Help is greatly appreciated,

Comment: Could you an image of the expected design?

Comment: I think you need `RoundedCornerShape`

Comment: Nah, roundedcornershape is just regular corner radius.